# Conexão webservice android

Tags: android, json, web-service, http-request

Olá, pessoal estou desenvolvendo um app na IDE do Android Studio e estou tendo problemas na conexão com meu webservice. Estou recebendo o erro: D/response: {"success":"false","message":"A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of location=25"}, segue o código. Alguém sabe como posso resolver este problema? Desde já muito obrigado.

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://MY_HOST");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location","25"));

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs, "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            serverData = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            Log.d("response", serverData);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu arquivo PHP não está gerando o JSON corretamente, essa pode ser a causa. Faça o teste no navegador e veja se ele está gerando o JSON, se é JSONArray, iniciando com [, ou se é JSONObject, iniciando com {. O log que você está capturando é da mensagem retornada na conexão, a mesma escrita no arquivo web usando o echo, caso seja em PHP.

Comment: Só respondi de primeira porque não consegui adicionar comentários ><

Comment: Estou recebendo essa mensagem no LogCat. O problema é que quando converto para Json Object antes de enviar ele não coloca como parametro a '{'.

Comment: Adicione à pergunta o seu JSON recebido do WebService para facilitar o entendimento.

Comment: Veja se isso pode ajudar: stackoverflow.com/questions/19399135/a-jsonobject-text-must-begin-with-error